# Issue with testing Acumos model locally on Docker

Tags: docker, acumos

Having issue with running downloaded model on Docker. Specifically, I entered two Docker commands and the second halted as shown below.

```
docker load -i facebookstarratings_1e087ab3-9e8f-42ef-b5ca-e3191d39847b_2.tar

Loaded image: acumos-devchallenge-nexus:18001/facebookstarratings_1e087ab3-9e8f-42ef-b5ca-e3191d39847b:2
```

```
docker run -p 3330:3330 acumos-devchallenge-nexus:18001/facebookstarratings_1e087ab3-9e8f-42ef-b5ca-e3191d39847b:2

Error in acumos:::run(metadata = "generator.json", payload = "generator.bin",  : 
  unused arguments (metadata = "generator.json", payload = "generator.bin", proto = "generator.proto")
Execution halted
```

Comment: I believe the generated microservice fails to start. What language are you using? Can you post the source code that generated the model you have on-boarded, or can you post a minimal code example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I am using R and the compose function to generate model file. I put everything on Github here including training data. https://github.com/datjandra/acumos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don_t,

Thanks for your patience. We identified an issue with the version of the R Acumos Client Library not matching what we had in the Acumos Onboarding module, causing the problem you saw when running your model.

There is now a new version of the R Acumos Client Library (0.2-7) which should fix this issue; please install this new version and re-onboard your model.

good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work now I'm getting following output: `docker run -p 3330:3330 acumos-devchallenge-nexus:18001/facebookstarratings_444407c5-fc5b-495e-9aca-e496cdb9cbd1:1
-- running Rserve in this R session (pid=1), 1 server(s) --
(This session will block until Rserve is shut down)`